# Load an Image error

Tags: java, image, javafx-2, fxml

I have a question.
I have 2 classes, 1 SampleController class and 1 other normal Class that i have made by myself.
(And offcourse the FXML file). 
I want to load an Image through a Pane at a click of a button.
But i want to load the image in through the other Class.
But those classes have to have controle to each other, which results in this error:

```
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
at blackjack.ControllerToImagesBridge.<init>(ControllerToImagesBridge.java:23)
at blackjack.SampleController.<init>(SampleController.java:27)
```

Does anyone know how i can solve this problem?
Thankyou very much.

Comment: The error itself is missing in exception tracktrace. Post that one.

Comment: And if you post the code it self, it would help a lot.

Comment: This link should give you acces to the files:https://db.tt/hKnJuOK7

Answer (score 0):

As your Error indicates: **recursive call**

```
public class SampleController implements Initializable 
{ 
    Card card = new Card();     
    Dealer deal = new Dealer();   
    Images images = new Images(card, deal); 
    SampleController sample;
```

or better her where you actually construct it

```
@Override public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) { 
      this.clickStartButton(null); 
      text.setEditable(false); 
      dealerscore.setEditable(false); 
      clickable = true; 
      firstcard = false; 
      extracard = false; 
      sample = new SampleController(); 
      bridge = new ControllerToImagesBridge(images, sample); 

      Image image = new Image("images/schoppen-A.png"); 
      ImageView view = new ImageView(image); 
      image1.getChildren().add(view); 
    }
```

notice the

`enter code here`sample = new SampleController();

and what you actually wanted to do was probably

```
this.sample = this;
```